# Forcing closed an open file by C#

Tags: c#, file-io, locking, move

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760481/closing-open-files-using-c) but it was closed/accepted with an answer of "don't do that".

I'm in a situation where I don't care what happens to the other applications, I want to take a file that may be locked by others (rudely if needed) and have my way with it.  I may need to move, rename, or delete this file.

Basically I need to process files in a directory that is created by an app that doesn't clean up it's locks.  I know the app is done processing when mine calls, but I need to kill the locks when I run.  In addition it seems I'm conflicting with reads from local AV software scanning the remote share where the server is.

All this adds up to an unresolvable "force close" situation so I can do what I need.  Does anyone have an idea on what to do?