# How to close existing handle on file in C#

Tags: c#, file, .net-4.0, handle

How can I close an existing handle on a file in C#? Is it possible?

Suppose I run code with administrator account? Can I just force the file to be closed?

In another post, one of the answer was to use interop:

```
[Flags]
enum MoveFileFlags {
    MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x00000001,
    MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED = 0x00000002,
    MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x00000004,
    MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x00000008,
    MOVEFILE_CREATE_HARDLINK = 0x00000010,
    MOVEFILE_FAIL_IF_NOT_TRACKABLE = 0x00000020
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, MoveFileFlags dwFlags);

static void delete() {
    string fileName = @"c:\temp\test.xlsx";
    bool success = false;
    foreach(var e in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MoveFileFlags))) {
        success = MoveFileEx(fileName, null, (MoveFileFlags) Enum.Parse(typeof(MoveFileFlags), e));
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} success : {1}", e, success));
    }
}
```

This solutions is not working. We need to reboot to delete the file.

Another example tells to kill the process:

```
string fileName = @"c:\aaa.doc"; //Path to locked file

Process tool = new Process();
tool.StartInfo.FileName = "handle.exe";
tool.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName;
tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
tool.Start();
tool.WaitForExit();
string outputTool = tool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string matchPattern = @"(?<=\s+pid:\s+)\b(\d+)\b(?=\s+)";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern)) {
    Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value)).Kill();
}
```

The problem is I don't want to kill the process, since the process that locks the file is IIS or Explorer.

I need to refresh file of a web site.

This is the solutions that I'm using and it is working fine:

```
static void delete(string fileName) {
    string handleTools = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "handle.exe");
    Process tool = new Process();
    tool.StartInfo.FileName = handleTools;
    tool.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName;
    tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    tool.Start();
    tool.WaitForExit();

    string outputTool = tool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<pid>pid:\s+[0-9]*)\s*(?<type>type:\s+\w*)\s*(?<handle>[A-F0-9]*:\s+)");
    Match match = reg.Match(outputTool);
    string pid = null;
    string handle = null;

    if (match.Groups["pid"].Value != null) {
        pid = match.Groups["pid"].Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pid)) {
            pid = pid.Replace("pid: ", string.Empty);
        }
    }
    if (match.Groups["handle"].Value != null) {
        handle = match.Groups["handle"].Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(handle)) {
            handle = handle.Replace("handle: ", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty);
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(handle) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pid)) {
        tool = new Process();
        tool.StartInfo.FileName = handleTools;
        tool.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-p {0} -c {1} -y", pid, handle);
        tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        tool.Start();
        tool.WaitForExit();
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
}
```

To use this solutions you will need to use [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) from sysinternal

Comment: How are you getting the handle ?

Comment: exact dup as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526802/forcing-closed-an-open-file-by-c-sharp

Comment: @parapura rajkumar , actually i dont know how to get the handle. But i imagine there a way to get the handle and close it

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?  Just flag it as a dup.

Comment: @CédricBoivin http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=force+close+file+C%23

Answer (score 2):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/04a1e899-2a38-4d95-8ed5-6d53344e4d76