# Understanding a self-deleting program in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

There is a self deleting program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
        sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

        CopyFile(argv[0], "1.exe", FALSE);
        MoveFile(argv[0], "2.exe");

        CreateFile("1.exe", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, &sa, 
            OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, NULL);

        CreateProcess(NULL, "1.exe x", NULL, NULL, 
            TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        while(!DeleteFile("2.exe"));

        CreateProcess(NULL, "net", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
            DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    }
}
```

If I remove this :`CreateProcess(NULL, "net", NULL, NULL, TRUE, DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);`
it can't work.
Could anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: If you convert this to use a wmain and run unicode, it doesn't work...  Odd.

Comment: Because the filename string is ascii coding .Maybe you can add _T() around stirng.

Comment: Haha, yeh I did that, it did compile, I mean it doesn't work at runtime.

Comment: Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: @MikeKwan - Actually it wouldn't work if they did close the handles ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an explanation (as I understand things)

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
        sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

        // Make a copy of ourselves which we'll use to delete the version we were run from
        CopyFile(argv[0], "1.exe", FALSE);

        // Rename the running copy of ourself to another name
        MoveFile(argv[0], "2.exe");

        // Make sure we delete the copy of ourselves that's going to delete us when we die
        CreateFile("1.exe", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, NULL);

        // Invoke the process that will delete us
        // allowing it to inherit the handle we just created above.
        CreateProcess(NULL, "1.exe x", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        // Wait for the original program to die (deleting us and closing a handle), then delete it
        while(!DeleteFile("2.exe"));

        // Launch a child process which will inherit our file handles
        // -- This keeps the file handle with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE (which we inherited) alive beyond our lifetime
        // this allowing us to be deleted after we've died and our own handle is closed.
        CreateProcess(NULL, "notepad", NULL, NULL, TRUE, DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean CreatProcess keep the Handle of this program? But I still don't understand how does it works. Does it mean if I remove it ,there's no enough time for the program to delete itself?

Comment: If the FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE handle is closed too early, the delete will fail because the 1.exe process is still running.  By launching a child which inherits the handle, The handle of 1.exe closes allowing it to be deleted when the child closes.

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: There's a slight race condition inherent in this because it relies on the fact that the child probably won't die more quickly than we die.

Comment: Btw, in regards to the crash when compiling with Unicode, it is because `lpCommandLine` is immutable: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/01/9673254.aspx